# jquery scroll and click in same function

Tags: jquery, scroll, click

I hope someone can help me in here. I have this jquery script which is implemented on this site. www.runebs.dk (the code is Rune)..

```
    $(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value
}); 

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var pos = $('#subHeadline').offset();
    $('.article-header').each(function() {
        if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
            $('#subHeadline').html($(this).html());
            return;
        }
    });

    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $(this).text($(this).text() == '(-)' ? '(+)' : '(-)');
        $('.description' ).slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

My problem is that when you scroll the + sign change to minus.. How can i avoid that?

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand what exactly you want.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but you should move the `$('button').click(...)` outside the scroll event handler.. Otherwise, the click-event will be bound for each trigger of scroll (which can be a lot) resulting in multiple clicks firing on one click.

Comment: I have tried to move the $('button').click(....) outside, but when i do that the click function doens´t work anymore. But I'm sure that the solution is something close to that..

Comment: How would you do it? Like this?

Comment: How can i add code again?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
//implement the functionality for the scroll
}).find("#buttonID").on("click", function(){
//write functionality for the button
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for the example.. Unfortunately when I try that the slideToggle don´t work.. any ideas?

Comment: How will the code you wrote above look with a if statement in the first function?